# Kafka Streams approach to timed window with max count

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have a system where we process text messages. Each message gets split up into sentences, and each sentence gets processed individually and the results of each sentence get published to a topic. This all happens asynchronously.

I want to be able to aggregate the results for the sentences.

The problem is that I want the window to end when the total number of sentences have been reached, or when a total amount of time has passed. Basically Tumbling time windows, but can end when a total number of results have been received.

Secondarily I want to be able to know when that window ends so that I can process the aggregation as an atomic event.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, what you are looking for is what some processing technologies call "triggers".  The Kafka Streams API, by design, does not support such triggers.  See https://www.confluent.io/blog/watermarks-tables-event-time-dataflow-model/ for an explanation of why this is the case.

Comment: Maybe. I think that I was expecting was some windowing mechanism that would allow me to aggregate grouped messages until a specific time. Extra credit would be to allow for the manual closing of the window (when some criteria has been met). Might be that last aspect that is making you think it is a trigger. The first part seems like it should be support by the Streams API, I just can't see it.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible but you have to implement a custom processor - your requirements are simply to specific for the high-level API to cater for.

Your processor would store messages into a state store and use punctuate to periodically check if the window expired. It would also keep a running counter and check if the max number of results have been received. If either condition is met, it does the aggregation, removes messages from the state store and sends the results downstream.

You'd have to think about what to do on restart (failover/re-balancing). When starting up, the processor should inspect its state store and calculate the current running count and the window expiry time.

Answer (score 0):

Now Apache Kafka offers you a way to wait closing the window. Here piece of code;

```
suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(Suppressed.BufferConfig.unbounded()))
```

For more, [check it out.](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-328%3A+Ability+to+suppress+updates+for+KTables#KIP-328:AbilitytosuppressupdatesforKTables-Newoperator:%22suppress%22)